# jqGrid drag and drop a copy of the row, rather than moving the row?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, clone

It's easy to connect two grids for Drag and Drop:

```
jQuery("#sourceGrid").jqGrid('gridDnD',{connectWith:'#targetGrid'});
```

However, this *moves* the row from source to target.  I want to *copy* the row from source to target.

The default "drag_opt" for gridDnd includes "helper: 'cone'", but it doesn't appear to be cloning.  Does anybody have a trivial addition to the above jqGrid that accomplishes *copy* rather than *move*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use

```
jQuery("#sourceGrid").jqGrid('gridDnD',
                             {connectWith:'#targetGrid',drag_opts:{stop:null}});
```

or

```
jQuery("#sourceGrid").jqGrid('gridDnD',
                             {connectWith:'#targetGrid',
                              drag_opts:{stop:function(event,ui) {/*do on drop*/}}});
```

Comment: The {stop:null} is a little abrupt but it works; I think I'll use the other approach with minimal additional code in the  /* do on drop */ area.  Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @John: You welcome! I think also that some code inside the /* do on drop */ would be better. It you find some problem with It is the `stop:null` way you will have to write his own `stop` event handle. At least it is the place where original jqGrid `stop` event handle remove dropped row from the source grid.

Answer (score 2):

Use the dragcopy option when setting up the DnD options:

```
jQuery("#sourceGrid").jqGrid('gridDnD',{connectWith:'#targetGrid', dragcopy: true});
```

[Link to documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#drag_and_drop_rows_between_grids)